# Validación entre dos campos de un modelo con condiciones booleanas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un Modelo llamado Asistencia. En éste, tengo dos campos `booleanos`  entre otros más, y necesito una validación que solo me acepte por ejemplo solo cuando `boolean1 sea "false"`, el  `boolean2 puede ser "true" o "false".
mientras que cuando el boolean1 sea "true" , no acepte el boolean2 como "true"

Aquí las condiciones:

- Si `boolean1 = false` , `boolean2` puede ser `true` o `false`
- Si `boolean1 = true`, `boolean2` tiene que ser `false` no aceptar `true`

Edición:

A ver si puedo explicarme mejor , el modelo que tengo como dije anteriormente se llama Asistencia , el cual lo tengo relacionado con otro modelo llamado Workers , la idea es que en mi formulario de asistencia yo agrego asistencias por fechas , estos dos campos booleanos que nombre anteriormente son "Asistió" , el cual es true si el trabajador si asistió y false si no , el otro campo booleano es "Excepcion" el cual tiene como fin que si el trabajador NO asistió , puede presentar una excepcion (presento una justificación o una licencia médica ese día que falto ) marque true , y sea false cuando no presento esta justificación .

Por lo tanto , cuando en mi booleano "Asistio" es true , osea que si asistió, no puede haber una excepcion .

Comment: modifiqué `boolean2` al final por `boolean1`. Entiendo que es así. Cualquier cosa no dudes en modificarlo o comentarlo.

Comment: Lo que vi esque dices que pusiste el valor de boolean1 en el boolean2 pero no cumple la primera condición, ya que boolean1 sera igual a boolean2 siempre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resumiendo, cuando `asistio` es `true`, `excepcion` debe ser `false`, ¿es eso?. Entonces podrías llamar a un callback como:

```
class Asistencia < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :sin_excepcion, if: :asistio?

  def sin_excepcion
    self.excepcion = false
  end
end
```

Ahora, si quieres hacer esto como validación en vez de callback, o sea que el usuario reciba un mensaje de error de validación en vez de que el propio sistema le cambie el campo `excepcion` a false, podrías probar con:

```
class Asistencia < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :excepcion, inclusion: [false], if: :asistio?
end
```

Personalmente pienso que es mas amigable para el usuario que el sistema te cambie los valores a que te entregue un error de validación, pero ahí verás que es lo que en realidad tú requieres.

Answer (score 0):

Para que cumpla las condiciones:

- Si Asistió = true , Excepcion es false
- Si Asistió = false, Excepcion puede ser true o false

Puedes crear una función que corra antes de las validacion declararla en tu modelo de la siguiente manera:

```
before_validation :validate_boolean1
    def validate_boolean1
        if self.asistio == true
            self.excepcion = false 
        end
    end
```

Edite  mi respuesta a como cambiaste tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola , edite mi pregunta para ver si puedes revisarla , gracias

Comment: Definitivamente la pregunta hace pensar en este tipo de respuestas

Answer (score -1):

No se si entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero si lo que se desea es asignar un valor a `true` a `boolean2`, ***siempre*** que `boolean1` sea `true`, esto te puede servir:

```
before_validation :validate_boolean1

def validate_boolean1
    if self.boolean1 == true
        self.boolean2 = true 
    end
end
```

Comment: Hola , edite mi pregunta a ver si puedes revisarla